# How to create a Source Zip File with Main.rvt and material image

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using forge design automation api in our project. But when I am viewing(in forge viewer) the output file generated by add in, its getting grayed out and texture are not appearing in the model.

I am not sure about that how the material textures file will be named inside the zip package. Can some please help me to create the source zip file containing main Revit and all other content (images, etc) that are necessary for the textures?

Textures are not appearing in model:

[image]

Comment: When you run the addin locally(revit desktop software), is result diferent?

Comment: Yes its working when we are running addin locally(revit desktop software), but when we open file in forge viewer(web) it not working.

Comment: please email the details of the file and bundle to forge.help@autodesk.com we'll take a look, if necessary we can have a zoom call.